# From photon flux to number of photons inside a cavity

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, optics, quantum-optics, cavity-qed

Consider a light beam with photon flux $\Phi$ entering a cavity. The latter consists of two mirrors, from which photons can enter/exit at rates $\kappa_1$, $\kappa_2$, respectively. How do I obtain the number of photons inside the cavity in the stationary state? What happens if the light is detuned by $\Delta$ from cavity resonance?

Answer (score 1):

In the interaction picture, the equations of motion for the cavity (assumed single mode by the OP) read:

$$ \dot{a}(t) = -(\kappa_1 + \kappa_2)a(t) + \eta(t). $$

The constants are defined as in the question and $\eta$ is the drive strength, which is related to $\Phi$ (if I understand ''photon flux'' correctly it is $\eta \propto \sqrt{\Phi}$. Otherwise more information about the quantum state is required). Note the absence of a detuning $\Delta_{\mathrm{cav}}$, since we are in an interaction picture that measures frequencies relative to the cavity mode frequency. We note that this approach even works for pulsed drives.

Since the equations are linear, they can be solved by Fourier transforms, to give the solution in the frequency domain:

$$a(\Delta) = \frac{\eta(\Delta)}{i\Delta + \kappa_1 + \kappa_2}.$$

The steady state photon population in the cavity for a steady state drive at detuning $\Delta$  is then given by $\langle a^\dagger(\Delta) a(\Delta)\rangle$.

Comment: To add to that: The driving stregth $\eta$ is related to the photon flux as $\eta = \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{ \left( \kappa_1 + \kappa_2 \right) \Phi}$. You find this by equating the overall leakage rate $\left( \kappa_1 + \kappa_2 \right) \left\langle a(0)^{\dagger} a(0) \right\rangle$ with the photon flux $\Phi$ and solving for $\eta$.
Another small addition: You use $\kappa$ as the field decay rate, while the OP uses $\kappa$ as energy decay rate. The energy decay rate is twice as high as the field decay rate.

Comment: @A.P. thanks for your comment! To respond to your points: 1. Something like that, but in general no! It depends on which side your driving laser/field comes from, so it should be either $\kappa_1$ or $\kappa_2$. Also for general cavities the drive coupling is not trivially related to the drive coupling, your relation only holds within the Markov approximation/for isolated resonances. (If you want I can give references, let me know). Also apart from that, there are probably some hbars etc in that relation, depending on if you use photon or energy flux. I stay away from units like that ;)

Comment: 2. The OPs usage of $\kappa$ was kind of vague. My usage is the standard. The factor of 2 is convention. I like decay *rates*, some people like line widths. Speaking of which: I found a minus sign error.

Comment: sry, in the first part, it should say „drive coupling is not trivially related to the decay rate“